# How to allow users to create slideshows in Drupal 7.14?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, slideshow

Please i am looking forward to add some modules in **Drupal 7.14** that allows my users to add a slideshow content (series of images with text). I would like to know as well if it is possible to categorise such type of content.

Which modules do you think are suitable for such purpose? or simply how someone can achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to what YoloTats said, you can also use Views slideshow module: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/

Since that is used with views as well, you can definitely categorize the content.  Just set up a new content type with fields for your images, text, and categories and then display all of those contents in a view with a slideshow display.  The views_slideshow module allows you to cycle through your content with a variety of transitions, pacing, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple modules you can use, here are several.  I like to use them with Views

http://drupal.org/project/flexslider

http://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider